# Can Visual Studio 2015 Professional and Community be installed on the same PC?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

**Question:** Is it possible to install both Visual Studio 2015 Professional and 2015 Community Edition on a PC, such that users with an MSDN subscription can use the Professional Edition and users without can use the Community Edition?

**Background:** I'd like to share my notebook with an intern. I have an MSDN subscription (and, thus, VS Pro is installed), but the intern doesn't. If possible, I'd like to avoid having to uninstall VS Pro while he uses the notebook.

Comment: The obvious thing to do is to try it. However, I think I have done this in the past. IIRC, it doesn't prompt you, or warn you, and effectively uninstalls pro whilst installing community and vice versa (so you think it's working and then realise that you're going to waste another few hours getting back to where you started from). And, so far as I can recall, there's no option to install VS as a per-user install rather than per-machine (as some installers offer).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That's exactly why I'm asking here on SO: I'd like to avoid those "wasted few hours" and learn from other people's mistakes. :-)

Comment: As an alternative to trying a side-by-side install - iif you have a MSDN subscription, can't you just spin up a VM on your computer and let your intern use that? You should have access to another OS license key via MSDN.

Comment: @Heinzi - unfortunately, it's the sort of thing that few people will try to do and even fewer will think to document it at the time such that they could offer a definitive answer later. As I said previously, I *think* I tried this. But I'm not certain enough to offer it as an answer since I may be recalling a different set of circumstances. Unfortunately, we may need you to use those hours and then self answer.